# How to check in Python if one tuple is an exact, ordered subsequence of the other?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples of various lengths and need to find a method to check if there are tuples that are an exact, ordered subsequence of one another. I will show with an example what I mean in this context:

Assume I have the following tuples:

```
t1 = (37, 5, 3, 22, 1)
t2 = (3, 5, 22)
t3 = (3, 22, 1)
t4 = (37, 41, 19)
```

Let's call the hypothetical function `check_sub_tuple`. Then the function should give the following outputs:

- `check_sub_tuple(t1, t2) = False`, (`t2` is not a subtuple of `t1`)
- `check_sub_tuple(t1, t3) = True`, (`t3` is a subtuple of `t1`)
- `check_sub_tuple(ti, tj) = False` for all other pairs of tuples `ti` and `tj` in the example

**Question 1**: Is there existing Python functionality for this? I know I could do this:

```
set(my_tuple_2).issubset(my_tuple_1)
```

But this just checks if the elements of one tuple are contained in the other, I also need the order to be the same.

**Question 2**: How can I do the exact same thing for lists instead of tuples?

Comment: Do you mean "subsequence"? Sub**sets** are unordered.

Comment: So your input is a list of lists/tuples?  What about the exact output in the example then? Just to confirm.

Comment: @Daniel Hao True, I either have a list with only lists or a list with only tuples, and I need to check which pairs of lists/tuples are subsequences of another

Comment: In case tuples consist of integers in `range(0, 256)`, you can use `bytes(ti) in bytes(tj)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this:

```
t1 = [37, 5, 3, 22, 1]
t2 = [3, 22, 1]

any(t2 == t1[i:i+len(t2)] for i in range(0,len(t1)))
```